# Can't be changed pin color when I change segement in mkMapView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, google-maps, mkmapview

I have some problem regarding Annotations in mapView. Lets have one glance on my requirement.

I want to give choice to user to choose location for meeting.

There are two options.

1) I should give list of near by data

Or

2) He can drag and drop pin anywhere he wants !

For that I have created one segment.
First index for near by data 
and
Second index for dropping a pin.

For First option (**"near by"**) I need to fetch near by data from **location of Seller, location of Buyer and midpoint between seller and buyer**. So I call google api and get data by passing latitude and longitude three times. There is no issue when I get data first time. My array fill up with all data (included 3 responses) and pin color also changes as per requirement.

Buyer (Red Color)
Seller ( Purple)
Mid Point (Green)

Now when I click on drop pin all data are removed from array and one pin is dropped on map.

Till now it works fine !

But when you again click on "near by", Problem starts ! No doubt it gives me data as I want but pin colors don't maintained.

```
-(MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation {

    if ([segmentND selectedSegmentIndex]==0) {

        if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]])
            return nil;

       static NSString* BridgeAnnotationIdentifier = @"bridgeAnnotationIdentifier";
        MKPinAnnotationView* pinView = (MKPinAnnotationView *)
        [myMapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:BridgeAnnotationIdentifier];
        if (!pinView)
        {
            MKPinAnnotationView* customPinView = [[[MKPinAnnotationView alloc]
                                                   initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:BridgeAnnotationIdentifier] autorelease];

            switch (self.pinColor) {
                case 0:
                {
                    customPinView.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorPurple;
                }
                    break;
                case 1:
                {
                    customPinView.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorRed;
                }
                    break;
                case 2:
                {
                    customPinView.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorGreen;
                }
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
            customPinView.canShowCallout = YES;

            UIButton* rightButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];


            [rightButton addTarget:self
                            action:@selector(showDetails:)
                  forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
            customPinView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = rightButton;

            return customPinView;
        }
        else
        {
            pinView.annotation = annotation;
        }
        return pinView;
    }
    else {

        // Code of dragging dropping pin. It works Fine.s
    }
}
```

I am attaching [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1AqNy.png) for more idea.

Please give me solution or any another way to implement it. **Remember Pin color is compulsory to differentiate Seller Buyer and Midpoint !**

Comment: just chk your switch condition that control goes inside it or nor using breakpoint

Comment: what value does self.pinColor holds?

Answer (score 1):

The trouble with your current approach is that self.pinColor doesn't change according to which annotation the map is needing a view for. It can and will call viewForAnnotation when ever it feels like it. Maybe the map has been scrolled around and one pin has just come back into view. Maybe the app was put into the background and is just being brought back into view by the user. What ever the reason you need to analyze the annotation is is passing in to determine which pin colour to use in the view. What object are you using for your annotation? If it was HSAnno and it had a property called pinColor you'd do something like this instead of your switch statement.

```
HSAnno* currentAnno = (HSAnno *)annotation;
pinView.pinColor = currentAnno.pinColor;
```

That way no matter what annotation needed to be redrawn viewForAnnotation would always return the right coloured pin.

Comment: There is no such class exists in my framework ! Is this third party code ?

Comment: The HSAnno class is one I made up as an example (When I was typing Hemang Shah's answer was above the text box and I took his initials instead of yours). The class doesn't really exist it's up to you to write one. You have to implement the MKAnnotationProtocol and add a property (which can be called pinColor or anything). Then when viewForAnnotation is called you cast the generic annotation object to your class (after checking it is not the userPin) and then set the pin's color based on the value of the property.

Answer (score 0):

You set your pincolor in that code part when no reusable pin exists.

```
if (!pinView)
    ....
    customPinView.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorPurple;
    ....
}
```

When `viewForAnnotation` is called and reusable pins are found they are used. There is where the wrong color pin is taken.

Set your pincolor in the

```
else
{
    pinView.annotation = annotation;
}
```

part and it should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Think its got mistaken here

```
    else
    {
        pinView.annotation = annotation;
    }
    return pinView;
```

Correct it to

```
    else
    {
        pinView.annotation = annotation;        
        return pinView;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's I little modified your code & `MKMapView` delegate. Previously you've changing `pin` color inside `if` that make it to call only for once when first time `MKMapView` loads.

```
-(MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation 
{            
    if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]])
        return nil;

    static NSString* BridgeAnnotationIdentifier = @"bridgeAnnotationIdentifier";
    MKPinAnnotationView* pinView = (MKPinAnnotationView *)
    [mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:BridgeAnnotationIdentifier];
    if (!pinView)
    {
        pinView = [[[MKPinAnnotationView alloc]
                                            initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:BridgeAnnotationIdentifier] autorelease];
    }
    else
    {
        pinView.annotation = annotation;
    }

    switch (self.pinColor) {
        case 0:
        {
            pinView.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorPurple;

        }
            break;
        case 1:
        {
            pinView.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorRed;
        }
            break;
        case 2:
        {
            pinView.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorGreen;
        }
            break;
        default:
            break;

    pinView.canShowCallout = YES;

    UIButton* rightButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];


    [rightButton addTarget:self
                    action:@selector(showDetails:)
          forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    pinView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = rightButton;

    return pinView;
}

    return pinView;
}
```

P.S. I've removed your first `UISegment` condition to check at my side, please add it as is, when you implement.

Comment: It works ! But same problem when I zoom in and zoom out on my map !

Comment: What happened when you zoom in and out?

Comment: Now I get all pins with random one color ( either purple, red or green)