# MKAnnotationView fault when zoom in/out changed the pin image

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, mkmapview, mkannotationview

I have used annotation map and used more than one image for the pins but whenever I zoom in or zoom out, it changes all the pins to one image.

I get the locations from a web service and to recognise them, I used a string (`CustAttr`) as "T" or "P".

The problem is the last call from a web service makes the `CustAttr = T` and when I zoom in or zoom out, it calls the mapView `viewForAnnotation` method and draws them all as `T` and all the `P` pins are changed.

Here is the code for the method :

```
-(MKAnnotationView*) mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation 
{

if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]]) {
    return nil;

}
static NSString* AnnotationIndentifer = @"AnnotationIdentifier";



if ([custAttr isEqualToString:@"T"]) // ATMs
{
    MKAnnotationView* pinView;
    pinView = [[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:AnnotationIndentifer];

    MapAnnotation* mapAnnotation = annotation;
    pinView.canShowCallout = YES;

    UIButton *rightButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeInfoLight];
    pinView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = rightButton;

    if (mapAnnotation.isClosest) {
        pinView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Closest_ATM.png"];

    }
    if (mapAnnotation.isOffline) {
        pinView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Offline_ATM.png"];
    }
    pinView.annotation = annotation;
    return pinView;        

}else if ([custAttr isEqualToString:@"P"]) // POIs
{
    MKAnnotationView* pinView;
    pinView = [[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:AnnotationIndentifer];

    pinView.canShowCallout = YES;
    pinView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Location_POI.png"];
    pinView.annotation = annotation;
    return pinView;
}

return nil;
}
```

How can I resolve this issue?  Is there a way that I can prevent it from calling this method when zooming in/out or is there another way to let it draw them again as in the same image?

Comment: Different wording, but the same base problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12210860/cant-be-changed-pin-color-when-i-change-segement-in-mkmapview/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `custAttr` variable (which you are setting outside the delegate method) will not always be in sync with the `annotation` that the `viewForAnnotation` delegate method is called for.

The delegate method is not necessarily called right after `addAnnotation` or `addAnnotations` and can be called multiple times for each annotation if the map needs to display the annotation view again after a zoom or pan.

When it gets called again for the same annotation, the `custAttr` variable no longer matches up.

You need to add a `custAttr` property (I suggest using a different name) to your `MapAnnotation` class and set it when creating the annotation (before calling `addAnnotation`).

For example:

```
MapAnnotation *ann = [[MapAnnotation alloc] init];
ann.coordinate = ...
ann.title = ...
ann.subtitle = ...
ann.custAttr = custAttr; // <-- copy to the annotation object itself
[mapView addAnnotation:ann];
```

Then, in `viewForAnnotation`, read the `custAttr` property from the *`annotation`* parameter (after casting it to `MapAnnotation *`) instead of referencing the externally declared `custAttr`.

You may want to use a different name for the `custAttr` property in `MapAnnotation` to avoid confusion.

Comment: thats was what i looking for ,,i should put it inside the object
many thanks to you