# How to use animated custom Pin (gif image) inside Mapview?

Tags: ios, animation, mapkit, gif

I want to add multiple pins on map which should remain animated continuously. Below are sample images which I want to use as Pin,

[image]

[image]

[image]

Is there any possible way to get this type of animated pin within MapKit? If possible then please suggest me appropriate way for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per my knowledge it is quite tough to implement. You can easily implement animation on any UIImageView but when you add any image on custom image then you can change custom pin image via using KVO or via NSTimer.

Please follow [Animation with MapView Custom Pin link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1857160/how-can-i-create-a-custom-pin-drop-animation-using-mkannotationview) to better understanding with custom pin annotation.

You can change pin image too after a certain period of time like as [Zooming change pin image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16491869/mkmapview-annotation-dynamic-pin-image-changes-after-zooming)

and  [Custom pin animation - MKMapView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2655465/custom-pin-animation-mkmapview).

I hope it will help you to better understanding. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could create a custom `MKAnnotationView` and give it a `UIImageView` as a subview.

Then, split the GIF into separate frames, to use in the `UIImageView`, [as documented in this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4386675/add-animated-gif-image-in-iphone-uiimageview).

Comment: Thanks...But I have an issue with Mapview pin image, not with simple ImageView.

Comment: thanks , that worked for me. I added UIIMageView to my MKAnnotationView